# Parse ddMMMyy date string with regex in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I wanted to make a regex such that the following date can be matched and its elements passed to another function:

```
"21Feb14"
```

Now the problem is the first two digits. The user can write a date in which the 'day' field is one-digit long OR two-digit long:

```
"21feb14" and "1jan13"
```

both are valid inputs.
the regex I made looks like this:

```
val reg = """(\\d)([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])(\d\d)""".r
```

It clearly does not take into consideration that the first digit may or may not exist. How do I handle that?

Comment: make it 2 digit
like 21feb14 or 01jan13  both are understandable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?` marks handles that. Like this,

```
(\d?\d)([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])(\d\d)
```

But I suggest you use following regex

```
(\d?\d)([a-zA-Z]{3})(\d\d)
```

Or with posix

```
(\d?\d)([\p{Alpha}]{3})(\d\d)
```

Answer (score 2):

This one is far more readable and maintainable

```
val reg = """(\d{1,2})([a-zA-Z]{3})(\d{2})""".r
```

Explanations here : http://regex101.com/r/uZ9qI5